# How to retrieve registry values remotley using vbs or batch files

Tags: vb6, batch-file, registry

I want to know, can I run a script on my computer that will return the value of a registry entry from another PC on the same network?

For instance if I wanted to know if a PC had AVG anti-virus installed, could I run a script to return the version number of AVG installed on that PC, and if it's not installed to just say it can't find it?

If it helps I know the IP, MAC address, Service TAG and computer name of the remote PC.

Comment: "No" and "know" are two very different words.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to reference [Connecting to WMI on a Remote Computer (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389290%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [Scripts to manage Registry](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/registry/)

Sample code would look something like this (taken from [ActiveXperts](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/registry/)):

```
const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
strComputer = "."
Set StdOut = WScript.StdOut

Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_ 
strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon"
strValueName = "UIHost"
oReg.GetExpandedStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,_
strValueName,strValue

StdOut.WriteLine  "The Windows logon UI host is: " & strValue
```

Where `strComputer` value would be replaced with the name / address of the machine.